# methods of prevent a user (or group) to be able to login

Tags: linux, security

is the only method to prevent a user from logging into the server setting the users shell to /dev/null?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to using `passwd -l` would be to use `passwd -d` and delete the user's password.

Comment: As dangerous as this sounds at first glance, it worked for me when I tested it. I was worried that it would allow a user to login with literally no password, but it doesn't. After investigating, I found that the PAM configuration line "password   requisite   pam_unix.so nullok obscure md5" treats any passwordless account as being locked, and it won't auth, even over something like telnet (which I tried). Good answer. +1

Comment: that's why it says "delete", and not "remove" :)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with ironchef regarding that configuring your sshd with AllowUsers or AllowGroups alternatively DenyUsers or DenyGroups might be a good solution, depending on what you are specifically trying to accomplish.

Regarding the option of setting a denying shell. If you have a /sbin/nologin available that might be preferable to /dev/null or /bin/false. Using /sbin/nologin will basicly have the same effect (non-zero exit), but with the extra bonus of the user getting a short message about the login being disabled.

Since you seem to want to keep the account around I assume you might be using them for something else? Depending on what that is, the locking of accounts may or may not be a good idea.

As already stated, please let people know what problem you are trying to solve, etc. Usually you can get a lot better advice that way.

Answer (score 0):

I would aks what you're trying to do to get a better idea.  For sake of expediency, if you only allow ssh as the access method, you can limit who can login by using AllowUser (only users explicitly in AllowUser will be allowed by sshd to login).

Answer (score 0):

You should set it to /bin/false instead of /dev/null.

`usermod -L myaccountname`
disables the password for that user

If the user have a SSH public key, you might wanna disable it too :
`rm /home/clem/.ssh/authorized_keys*`
(use mv if you want to restore it later)
You could also explicitely restrict allowed users with sshd's AllowUser directive (in /etc/ssh/sshd.conf).

Answer (score 0):

Pam_access provides a good method to restrict access to a subset of users.  Check out "man pam_access" for more details.  The pam configuration will have to be modified.  Most of the configuration happens in /etc/security/access.conf.  This module is pretty flexibly in restricting access to just particular users, or users who belong in particular groups.  The restrictions can be applied across all services, or just to particular services, depending on where pam_access is included within pam.

I've actually gone as far as running two separate access.conf like files, using one for shell access, and one for ftp/rcp access.  Pam_access allows us to maintain separate policies for various protocols.  The downfall of this flexibility is the configuration is a bit more complex, which may not be needed.